# MySQL8 Restore from Physical Files - Innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, restore, recovery

I recently had one of my VM's go down (MS Server 2016) and the only version I am able to get up and running is two weeks old. However, I do have a backup of my C:/ drive from last night that has my `C:/ProgramData/MySQL` and `C:/Program Files/MySQL` in order to restore my databases can I simply shut down MySQL service, copy/replace the folders in my VM, and start MySQL again?

**[SOLVED] As stated in the comment below:**

Copying the entire `C:/ProgramData/MySQL` folder did not work for me, the MySQL service would not start. Instead, copying just the contents of `C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data` solved the problem. The service started with no errors and all my data was recovered.

Comment: Should work if you copy the entire tree.

Comment: oddly enough, copying the entire C:/ProgramData/MySQL folder did not work, the service would not start. So i only copied over the contents of the C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data folder and the service started right up with all my data!

Comment: @A.O. you should post your answer in the popper answer box.